# porque la secuencia parece no detenerse?

Tags: javascript, css

Estoy añadiendo y retirando clases a 5 divs aleatoriamente en una ronda de 10 para que parezca que se iluminen: los colores prenden y apagan adecuadamente, pero cuando se termina la secuencia se me abre el debugger y se detiene en `colores[color].classList.add('light')`, como si al final tratara de añadirle la clase que ilumina a un div que no encuentra, ¿alguna idea?

```js
const boton = document.getElementById('btnEmpezar')
const verde = document.getElementById('verde')
const amarillo = document.getElementById('amarillo')
const azul = document.getElementById('azul')
const rojo = document.getElementById('rojo')
const blanco = document.getElementById('blanco')

const colores = {
  verde,
  amarillo,
  azul,
  rojo,
  blanco
}

let secuencia = new Array(10).fill(0).map(n => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))

function hideButton() {
  boton.classList.add('hide')
  iluminarSecuencia()
}

function iluminarSecuencia() {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    const color = transformarNumeroAColor(secuencia[i])
    setTimeout(() => iluminarColor(color), 1000 * i)
    console.log(color)
  }
}

function iluminarColor(color) {
  colores[color].classList.add('light')
  setTimeout(() => this.apagarColor(color), 350)
}

function apagarColor(color) {
  colores[color].classList.remove('light')
}

function transformarNumeroAColor(numero) {
  switch (numero) {
    case 0:
      return 'rojo'
    case 1:
      return 'verde'
    case 2:
      return 'amarillo'
    case 3:
      return 'azul'
    case 4:
      return 'blanco'
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.gameboard {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 260px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 5%;
  position: relative;
}

.polen {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  top: calc(0% - 50px);
  left: calc(-20% - 200px);
}

.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.uno {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.767);
  position: relative;
}

.dos {
  background-color: rgb(49, 122, 55);
}

.tres {
  background-color: rgb(213, 224, 46);
  position: relative;
}

.cuatro {
  background-color: rgb(194, 13, 13);
}

.petado {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(252, 255, 55);
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border-top-left-radius: 60%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

.petado.light {
  background-color: rgb(252, 253, 201);
}

.petado.dark {
  background-color: rgb(195, 197, 48);
}

.petaun {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 60%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.petaun.light {
  background-color: rgb(255, 129, 129);
}

.petaun.dark {
  background-color: rgb(177, 0, 0);
}

.petatre {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgb(79, 255, 88);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
}

.petatre.light {
  background-color: rgb(198, 253, 201);
}

.petatre.dark {
  background-color: rgb(67, 204, 74);
}

.petacua {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}

.petacua.light {
  background-color: rgb(138, 138, 255);
}

.petacua.dark {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 211);
}

.polen {
  position: absolute;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  top: calc(50% - 33px);
  left: calc(50% - 33px);
}

.polen.light {
  background-color: rgb(133, 127, 127)
}

.polen.dark {
  background-color: rgb(207, 205, 205);
}

.boton {
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgb(27, 26, 26);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: calc(50% - 31px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: right;
}

.boton.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <div class="gameboard">
  <div class="box uno light">
    <div id='rojo' class="petaun" data-color="red"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box dos light">
    <div id="amarillo" class="petado" data-color="yallow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box tres light">
    <div id="verde" class="petatre" data-color="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box cuatro light">
    <div id="azul" class="petacua" data-color="blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="blanco" class="polen" data-color="polen"></div>
  <button id="btnEmpezar" class="boton" onclick="hideButton()">Empezar!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: solo tienes 4 secuencias pero en el `for` estás iterando 10 veces. Ahí está el problema.

Comment: Como dice @hawks, sólo tienes 5 elementos, cuando `i` es mayor que 4, `transformarNumeroAColor` devolverá `undefined`. Podrías hacer `numero % 5` para que siempre devuelva un número entre 0 y 4.

Answer (score 2):

Esto ocurre porque el array tiene 10 elementos pero se le está indicando al loop que continue mientras que i sea menor o igual que 10. La clave está en ese =.

El primer elemento de una array se encuentra en la posición 0. Por lo tanto, cuando el loop llegue a la posición 10, no encontrará ningún elemento porque el último se encuentra en secuencia[9]. Es decir, cuando la variable i sea igual a 9, se habrá llegado al final del array.

Si ejecutamos el siguiente código, se ve con más claridad:

```
const ANIMALES = ["gato", "oso", "perro", "tigre", "vaca", "rinoceronte", "mosca", "hurón", "conejo", "hormiga"];

mostrarAnimales(ANIMALES);

function mostrarAnimales(animales) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= animales.length ; i++) {
    console.log( i + ': ' + animales[i]);
  }
}
```

Lo que se mostraría en consola sería:

```
0: gato
1: oso
2: perro
3: tigre
4: vaca
5: rinoceronte
6: mosca
7: hurón
8: conejo
9: hormiga
10: undefined
```

Por lo tanto, basta con quitar el = del "<=10" y dejar la función así:

```
function iluminarSecuencia() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const color = transformarNumeroAColor(secuencia[i])
    setTimeout(() => iluminarColor(color), 1000 * i)
    console.log(color)
  }
}
```